# Cannot initialize a parameter of type NSEvent* with an rvalue of type void

Tags: objective-c

Hello. I am trying to monitor the keys a user presses in a cacao app.

I used this code:

```
 // this code works!
 CGEventMask keyboardMaskKeyDown = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown);

 keyboardEventresult = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:keyboardMaskKeyDown handler:^(NSEvent *keyboardEvent)
 {
      keyboardEventresult = keyboardEvent;
      _currentKeystr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[[keyboardEvent characters]characterAtIndex:0]];
      NSLog(@"Pressed key: %@",_currentKeystr);
      [hiddentextfield setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_currentKeystr]];
  }];
```

But the problem is that when I change:

```
 addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask
```

to

```
 addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask
```

I am getting an error saying`Cannot initialize a parameter of type NSEvent *(^)(NSEvent *_strong) with an rvalue of type void(^)(NSEvent *_strong)`

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html) you can see that apple is doing something similar

```
         _eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:

        (NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSRightMouseDownMask | NSOtherMouseDownMask | NSKeyDownMask)

        handler:^(NSEvent *incomingEvent)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're passing the wrong type of parameter.  It's expecting `NSEvent *(^)(NSEvent *_strong)` (a block taking one argument of type `NSEvent*` and returning `NSEvent*`), but you're passing is a `void(^)(NSEvent *_strong)` (a block taking one argument of type `NSEvent*` and returning `void`.  Note the difference in the return types of the blocks—they must match exactly.

To fix this, make your block return an `NSEvent*`.  According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask%3ahandler%3a), you need to "return the event unmodified, create and return a new NSEvent object, or return nil to stop the dispatching of the event."  So add a `return <something>;` statement to the end of your block, where `<something>` is the same event, a new event, or `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice it :)